# Как правильно делать import в xcode из папки Pods?

Tags: xcode, react-native, импорт, sip, pjsip

Добавил в React-Native библиотеку: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sip2

Однако при компиляции ругается в одном из файлов

```
#import <VialerPJSIP/pjsua.h>         'VialerPJSIP/pjsua.h' file not found
```

Добавил в Podfile строку с библиотекой и запустил pod install

```
pod 'Vialer-pjsip-iOS'
```

В xcode в папке Pods появилась библиотека Vialer-pjsip-iOS и в разделе Target появилась строка Vialer-pjsip-iOS.

А как теперь к ней указать пути для импорта?

Comment: По инструкции https://github.com/telefon-one/react-native-sip2/blob/master/docs/installation_ios.md прошлись? Сейчас не нужно что ли компилировать pjsip отдельно? Несколько лет назад, когда пришлось с ней плотно поработать, все начиналось со сборки pjsip.

Comment: Да конечно. Всё перевыполнял по несколько раз.

Comment: Файлы этой библиотеки в iOS проект как добавляются? Как часть проекта или pod?